# How to preserve order for cards in a Kanban board in Google Cloud NDB?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, data-structures, nosql, ndb

I'm building a Kanban board and I want to preserve the order of cards that appear on my Kanban board.

I have explored the possibility of storing the keys of the cards in an Array attribute in an NDB model but the limit on that is only 1mb for a column and a Kanban column can have thousands of cards. If I create multiple rows, I will have to perform many actions to shift items if I'm adding a new card in the middle of one of the rows or shuffling the cards.

I also tried going with a linked list but that will mean a lot of read queries for finding the next node from the foreign key stored in the previous node.

NDB is the bottleneck here. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this without losing performance?